# VB aspx send string to another page not working on chrome (works fine in IE)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a aspx that open up as a popup and shows a callendar. On selection of a date it transfers that value to the original page. The problem is that it doesn't work on Google Chrome. It works fine in IE and EDGE. Here is the code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">


    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        control.Value = Request.QueryString("textbox").ToString()
    End Sub
    
      Protected Sub Muda_Data(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim strScript As String = "<script>window.opener.document.forms(0)." + control.Value + ".value = '"
        strScript += calData.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        strScript += " 23:59:59';self.close()"
        strScript += "</" + "script>"
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "ok", strScript)
      End Sub


</script>


<html>
<head>
<title>Calendário</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:Calendar ID="calData" OnSelectionChanged="Muda_Data" Runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="200px" Width="232px" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="1" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" >
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="White" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Height="8pt" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="#333399" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="12pt" />
    <DayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
</asp:Calendar>
<input type="hidden" id="control" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried same result : /

Comment: Another possibility is using `parent.opener.document.getElementById('controlname').value = '<value>'`. That seems to work ok in Chrome and IE.